# What is the time complexity of CUDA's 'thrust::min_element' function?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, time-complexity, thrust

Thrust library's documentation doesn't provide the time complexities for the functions. I need to know the time complexity of this particular function. How can I find it out?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: Note that `thrust::min_element` is implemented with `thrust::reduce`, so they will have the same time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The min-element algorithm just finds the minimum value in an unsorted range. If there is any way to do this in less than linear O(n) time-complexity, then my name is Mickey Mouse. And any implementation that would do worse than linear would have to be extremely badly written.

When it comes to the time complexities of algorithms in CUDA Thrust, well, they are mainly a CUDA-based parallelized implementation of the STL algorithms. So, you can generally just refer to the STL documentation.

The fact that the algorithms are parallelized does not change the time-complexity. At least, it generally cannot make the time-complexity any better. Running things in parallel simply divides the overall execution time by the number of parallel executions. In other words, it only affects the "constant factor" which is omitted from the "Big-O" analysis. You get a certain speed-up factor, but the complexity remains the same. But there is usually difficulties / overhead associated with parallelizing, and therefore, the [speedup is rarely "ideal"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup). It is only very rarely that the complexity is reduced, and it's only for some carefully-crafted fancy dynamic programming algorithms, not the kind of thing you'll find in CUDA Thrust. So, for Thrust, it's safe to assume all complexities are the same as those for the corresponding or closest-matching STL algorithm.